# How does Flutter manage separate navigation stacks with BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am really confused about how `Flutter` manages multiple navigation stacks at once, and switches between them with the `BottomNavigationBar`. So far I have managed to swap the `body` of my root `Scaffold` with `Widget`s, and can also change state on the `Scaffold` to change the `AppBar` title and set the index of the `BottomNavigationBarItem`. I can also see how setting `routes` on the `MaterialApp` will allow me to push and pop other screens. The problem is that when you have a tab bar navigation pattern, you want to be able to manage separate stacks. If I am 3 levels deep into a section and switch tabs, I expect to be in the stack for that particular section, and be able to jump between them.

How is this managed with Flutter? Ideally, the app should have a Main App `Scaffold` to define the `BottomNavigationBar`, the `Drawer`, and the main logic for switching between the different root level screens. These Screens should then manage their own `AppBar` and related `actions` for that section.

I'd really like to understand this before I go any further with `Flutter`, because right now, the thought of having to manage everything with one `Scaffold` fills me with dread.

I'm guessing that when you use `Navigator` it uses the `Context` to keep the stacks within the context of the screen that initiated the push, but I still don't understand how it keeps the `Scaffold` separate.

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could possibly be the answer: https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386 - towards the end of the article he talks about using separate Navigators per screen.

Answer (score 1):

This wonderful article gives me the answer: https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386

You need to use an `IndexedStack` for your main section switcher, and then use a `Widget` that returns a `Navigator` for each of the main sections. This `Navigator` sets the routes for that section (if known), but could just be the root.

I don't know if there is already a navigation pattern, or naming convention used by the Flutter community for this, but I have used `$(Section)Navigator`. Here's an example of a `StatelessWidget` I created for my test:

```
class DashboardNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            switch (settings.name) {
              case '/':
                return DashboardRoot();
              case '/login':
                return ScreenLogin(destination: allDestinations[0]);
              default:
                return DashboardRoot();
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This was mainly taken from Hans Muller's article which has been a great help.